# Unable to find the type of the USB port

Tags: usb

I have an old Megaudio MP3 player with a strange kind of USB port which I have never seen before. 
So, I just want to know what kind of USB port is this.
And from where i can get cable for this port.

[image: picture of unknown port]

Comment: What makes you think this is a USB port?

Comment: It came with a USB cable for trasferring data from PC ,then the cable got misplaced, so, I wanna know what it's called

Comment: Just because you have a cable with an USB plug on one end doesn't mean the other end is also USB - it's common for "cables" to contain some sort of chip which does protocol conversion. Also, a picture where one could actually see something would help, as would the exact model of the MP3 player.

Comment: It definitely is a USB port. It was used on many MP3/MP4 players. It's for charging and to move data. I have one in my hand, I'll try to find out more about it.

Comment: @dirkt It's even more common for the other end to be regular USB in some proprietary-shaped connector. E.g. iPod, Nokia, Sony all had their own connectors with USB pins. Chips in the device are cheaper than chips in the cable, I'd think.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## It's a *USB-MINI4P* port.

See the following chart:

[image: USB Ports]

It was used a lot for MP3/MP4 players in the past and is also used on a lot of digital cameras. It's indeed just a "regular" USB port used for charging and/or to transfer data. The cables usually don't contain a special chipset or anything like that.

You can get a cable for example [from amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01N7IWPM4).

---

A better picture of the connector in question:

[image]

---

As noted by [Ale..chenski](https://superuser.com/users/620011/ale-chenski), this connector is not part of the official USB standards and *might* not be conform to some stricter USB specifications.

Comment: Where did you get this "classification"?

Comment: @Ale..chenski What do you mean? I own a couple devices with such plug, googling around revealed the name and the chart I attached to my answer. There are plenty of devices with such connector and all of those I found/own have the USB chipset built into the device, not the cable. But I'm sure there are exceptions, that's why I said "usually" in my answer. I've updated  my answer to add a better picture of the connector.

Comment: I mean that USB specifications define only Type-A, Type-B, micro/mini variants thereof, and Type-C connectors. The rest are proprietary hacks to fit into their particular formfactors, before the standardization of u-AB connectors. These proprietary connectors don't have rights to be called "USB connectors". For example, I can get any 4-pin 0.1" header, and solder four wires to mating plug. Would you call it also as "USB-0.100" connector? No. That's why I object to calling these proprietary hacks as "USB Connectors".

Comment: @Ale..chenski I said basically the same in a comment to another answer that got deleted. It's a very common plug that is being used only (as far as I could find) for USB, that's why I compared it to that. But yes, I agree which is why I put the *"regular"* in quotes. I'd still call them "USB connectors" because after all, that's what you use to connect to it. I'd call Apple's 30-pin a "USB Connector" too, even though we both agree that technically and by standard it's not exactly the case.

Comment: I don't argue that the connectors were not used or else. The problem with that approach (to call every connector used for USB as "USB connector") is that these connectors may not conform to stringent USB-IF certification gauntlet, and have no due process to be certified to use in USB framework. It is like illegally using a valuable trademark.

Comment: @Ale..chenski I *think* they do conform to that, as most of the connectors in the chart I posted do, but I'm really having a hard time finding more about that connector or its origin. I've added a note to the end of my answer though for clearification, just in case.

Comment: Did you take those photographs?  If not, you should give credit to the source.

Comment: @Scott It's near impossible to find the original source for them. A google reverse-image search for the first picture reveals hundreds of results. [Here's one of them](https://eeeprojectz.blogspot.com/2015/04/types-of-usb-connectors.html). The second picture I got [from here](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/micro-usb-jack-4p-4-pins-mini-usb-connector-charging-port-socket-power-socket-for-mobile/32556547278.html).

Answer (score 0):

USB specifications define only Type-A, Type-B, micro/mini variants thereof, and Type-C connectors. The rest are proprietary solutions invented to fit into older devices in small formfactors, before the standardization of mini and micro-AB connectors. There are many non-standard types of such connectors, aka "Mitsumi connector", "HiRose", Sony-Samsung, Panasonic, etc etc. They also can be found as ["Juye Serial / Data Port Jack- USB Special" and "MINI-4P"](http://www.pchub.com/uph/laptop/1290-114822-27092/Juye-Serial-Data-Port-Jack-USB-Special.html) connector, as ["confetti"](https://superuser.com/a/1354020/620011) reported.

[image]

That's why you have difficulty to find the name for it, and it will be even more difficult to find and procure a mating plug for it, only by visual match.

The kind of connector shown in the question should be called "proprietary non-standard 4-pin connector" "frequently used in old MP3 players and some cameras".
These proprietary connectors don't have formal rights to be called "USB connectors". These connectors may not conform to stringent USB-IF certification gauntlet, and have no due process to be certified to use in USB framework. By using "USB" designation, the quality of real USB connectors are transferred to these by assumption. It is like illegally using a valuable USB trademark.

Comment: Did you take that photograph?  If not, you should give credit to the source.

Comment: @Scott, the source is in the link.